# MongoDB CRM Database Design Efficiency

Tags: mongodb

In my CRM I plan to be able to support a scale of 100 businesses for now, but ideally this would scale to any size.

The way it's set up right now:

Each business has 3 sections of data
Each section has 1000 "entries"
Each entry has 30 - 50 "data chunks" - Each data chunk has an id, an entry that it corresponds to, a value to indicate which type of data it is, and the value it's holding.

100 * 3 * 1000 * 30 = 9000000 pieces of data.

I'll normally only be pulling 100 entries at any given time so only 3000-5000 or so data chunks being pulled, but once in a while it could be as many as 1000 entries or more at once.

I have collections for businesses, sections, entries, and data chunks.

I'm setting it up this way because some business will be keeping different kinds of data than others and an SQL database doesn't really work with that.

A sample generation of data might look like this:

- find one section by name (ie business1 has a section called section1)
- find 100 entries for that section
- find 30 data pieces for each of those entries

That'd result in 101 find calls. I could also do the find call for the entries and then a find call for the data with a where array that has 100 or key/value pairs, which would pull 100 data entries where their entry id was one of those 100 or key/value pairs.

Is this a scalable database design? Is there a better way I should be doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting all of that related data in separate collections is almost certainly not a good choice. I'll remind you that mongodb does not have any joins by design, so you're going to have a hell of a time gathering data chunks using the entries and sections collections.

Because your spec is pretty vague (I have no idea what a section, entry, or data chunk represents), it's hard to say exactly how to design this. But to me, maybe 2 collections - 1 for businesses, 1 for data chunks is in order. Then just have the entry and section ids as fields on your data chunk documents.

Comment: See my edits for a bit more clarity. I think this would effectively be as efficient as your suggestion.

Comment: presumably you would want to return all data for some section, yes? so it would not be 101 find calls, it would be 1 find call to get the section, 1 find call to get the 100 entries, then 1 find to get the 30 * 100 data pieces. but why would you want to do 3 table joins for the central query in your database? if you want to do it this way, don't use mongodb, use a SQL database with joins, because you're emulating joins here

Comment: The joins are fairly efficiently simulated it seems, especially if I'm only doing a couple rather than 100. I'm not using an SQL database for this reason: Each data chunk has a 'value' field. That value can store any type of data, and that data is sortable in mongodb. If it were sql I wouldn't be able to do that efficiently.

Comment: it's not efficient to do 3 queries. it would not be usable if you were doing 100.  if you want to ignore my advice on database design after asking for advice on database design, you could also look at postgres which supports the JSON data type and can also do joins

Comment: I'm not ignoring your advice. I didn't know postgres supported JSON. I'll look into that.

Comment: yup they support json stored as binary as well so you can properly index and have good querying. but it's not a bad idea to use mongodb for this. I said you're ignoring my advice because you asked for a more efficient way to store this type of data, I gave it to you, and told me you wanted to use the less efficient way. up to you.

Comment: I will switch to postgreSQL for the efficiency of join - The only reason I was using mongodb was for JSON functionality.